# Combine detectors in Bag of visual words

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, image-recognition, matlab-cvst

I am using Bag of visual words for classification. 
I have quantized SIFT descriptor into 100 words for each image and encoded the histogram of the images and have completed classification.

Now, I want to try to combine two different descriptors and detectors i.e. SIFT and SURF, which means neither the number of key points will be the same nor will be the descriptor dimensionality  (SIFT 128D and SURF 64D).

What will be the easiest way to combine them?

If, for each image, I encode one histogram for SIFT (which will be a 100x1 histogram) and another for SURF (another 100x1)  and then stack them together making 200x1 histogram, will that be correct?

Any other way?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In bag of words, the number of key points or the descriptor size is irrelevant, once you generate the code book, you get a histogram whose dimensions are dependent on your codebook size. Again, the histogram is normalized, so it does not depend on the number of features detected per image. Suppose you have SIFT and SURF features, all you need to do is generate 2 codebooks and concatenate them to get a feature vector.

A brief overview of the method is mentioned here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision

Comment: Thanks. I have tried with combination and only get improved results in case the original performance of both SIFT and SURF are comparable.